# Repeatedly prompted to restart the computer when installing SQL Server 2008 R2 on a x64 Win 8.1 machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-8.1, powershell-v4.0

I am trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Win 8.1 x64 bit machine. 
When running the installer, I get the Reboot Required check failing the install.

I have tried rebooting, no difference.

I have looked in the following registry location to remove data from the " PendingFileRenameOperations" registry file:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager

The above mentioned file does not exists, instead I have FileRenameOperations, but there is no data, just a Default value - it is blank.

I have tried using the following Powershell command to run the .exe without being prompted for the Reboot Check:

- C:\FredISVSQL2008Workgroup\setup.exe \SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck

The command runs, the installer opens but the same reboot check is appearing.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks